# Multiple ContextLoader definition in web.xml

Tags: spring

I encountered this `"Cannot initialize context because there is already a root application context present - check whether you have multiple ContextLoader* definitions in your web.xml!"` error.

How I defined my listener and context param:

```
< listener > 
< listener-class > org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener < /listener-class >
< context-param >
< param-name > contextConfigLocation < /param-name >
< param-value > /WEB-INF/applicationContext.xml,/WEB-INF/applicationContext-securityBeans.xml < /param-value >
```

It was working fine when I was using Spring 3.1.2, Spring Security 3.1.4. I did an upgrade to Spring 4.1.1 and  Spring Security 3.2.5 and got this error.

May I know how I may resolve this error?

Thanks in advance!
Whiskers

Comment: Post the full stack/error. Make sure you don't have a `WebApplicationInitializer` in your path that also registers a root context.

Comment: No, I do not have the WebApplicationInitializer in my path.

Comment: No, I do not have the WebApplicationInitializer in my path. The error is java.lang.IllegalStateException: Cannot initialize context because there is already a root application context present - check whether you have multiple ContextLoader* definitions in your web.xml! At org.sprimgframework.web.context.ContextLoader.initWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:277) at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener.contextInitialized(ContextLoaderListener.java:106)..

Comment: Please don't add stacks/errors/code as comments, improve your post. As mentioned please post the full stacktrace.

Comment: any solution to this please ?